# C++ template instantiation depending on if clause

Tags: c++, templates

At the moment I'm doing:

```
if(dimension == 2)
{
    typedef itk::Image<short, 2>      ImageType;
    typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, 2>   IntegralImageType;
    m_pApp->train<2, ImageType, IntegralImageType>();
}
else
{
    typedef itk::Image<short, 3>      ImageType;
    typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, 3>   IntegralImageType;
    m_pApp->train<3, ImageType, IntegralImageType>();
}
```

But I would like to do:

```
    if (dimension == 2)
    DIMENSION = 2;
    else
    DIMENSION = 3;

    typedef itk::Image<short, DIMENSION>      ImageType;
    typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, DIMENSION>   IntegralImageType;
    m_pApp->train<DIMENSION, ImageType, IntegralImageType>();
```

I wasn't able to do it because c++ wants const variables for the template instantiation.
Is there so way to do it nevertheless?

Comment: If you have many dimensions you can define a template that handles the dispatch for you, so you wouldn't even have to write the `switch`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a function with a template parameter:

```
template<unsigned N>
void train(){
    typedef itk::Image<short, N>      ImageType;
    typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, N>   IntegralImageType;
    m_pApp->train<N, ImageType, IntegralImageType>();
}
```

then:

```
if (dimension == 2)
    train<2>();
else
    train<3>();
```

Note that this code will *instantiate* both templates (code will be generated for them), since at compile-time there is no way to know which one will be used.

Comment: Ok that was easy thanks alot!
My code instantiates both as well, I'm ok was that.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this:

```
const int N = DIMENSION == 2 ? 2 : 3;
typedef itk::Image<short, N>      ImageType;     
typedef itk::Image<unsigned int, N>   IntegralImageType;     
m_pApp->train<N, ImageType, IntegralImageType>();
```

Comment: No you can't. Even though N is constant, it is a runtime value, which is not known at compile-time. Hence, it cannot be used as a template parameter.